# UILocalNotification iOS8 handleActionWithIdentifier never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, uilocalnotification

I have create a local Notification in this mode:

AppDelegate.m in lunch

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        // Setup each action thar will appear in the notification
        UIMutableUserNotificationAction *acceptAction = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        acceptAction.identifier = @"ACCEPT_ACTION"; // Identifier is returned in handleActionWithIdentifier: after the user taps on an action
        acceptAction.title = @"ACCEPT_TITLE";
        acceptAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground; //Brings the app into the foreground when action tapped

        UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *not_cat = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
        not_cat.identifier = @"testCategory";

        [not_cat setActions:@[acceptAction] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:not_cat, nil];

        UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:categories];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    }
```

then I create a local Notification:

```
+ (void)sendLocalNotification:(NotificaObject*)n
{
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    // Set the category to the category that contains our action
    localNotif.category = @"testCategory";
    localNotif.alertBody = @"First Test mex, no action";//n.titolo;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"0" forKey:@"id"];
    localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]; //5 seconds
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    NSLog(@"Sending Local notification");
}
```

When Notification FIRE if the app (iOS8) is FOREGROUND 
in AppDelegate is called

```
 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

and NEVER call

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

if the app (iOS8) is in the Background is only call didReceiveLocalNotification

I can't figure out why handleActionWithIdentifier NEVER call

I use xcode6.01 and developing for ios7/8, What am I doing wrong??

Comment: This will get called when you select some action on Notification like clicking on button...Refer to this link...https://github.com/sgup77/SGNotification

Answer (score 1):

Dude. It seems you are registering for Remote Notification and putting handler for Local notification. Please register for Local Notification to get the listeners working.

Answer (score 0):

Do you attach any dispatch_get_main_queue?

I do a loop in main queue, and application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler: method is never called

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    while (YES) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
});
```

Solution is using dispatch_get_global_queue

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    while (YES) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just three steps for local notifications:

1.- in the AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you tell you app is working with notifications:

```
if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:")))
    {
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Sound | .Alert | .Badge, categories: nil))
    }
```

2.- Write a handler for the nofications (what's going to happend when the local notificion happens):

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    println("notification is here. Open alert window or whatever")
    // Must be called when finished
    completionHandler()
}
```

3.- In your app you set the local notification in this way:

```
 var localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Your Alarm!"
    localNotification.alertBody = "Your description"
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10) // your time
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName 
    // there are more and different options
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

For me it's working with ios 8.3 and swift 1.2